# Can't get value from POST

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, forms, foreach

This is part of an update page I created where I can make certain images private if ticked.
This is my form:

```
/* MYSQL rows - Photo ID & Privacy */

$photo_id = $row['id'];
$photo_private = $row['private'];

    
/* Privacy setting for photo(s) */

if ($photo_private == "1") {

    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="private_photo['.$photo_id.']" value="1" checked>';

       } else {

     echo '<input type="checkbox" name="private_photo['.$photo_id.']" value="0">';

 }
```

And below is the page my form submits to. I can get the photo ID fine, but I don't know how to get the value="x" to save into $value

```
foreach ($_POST['private_photo'] as $plz_pvt) {

        $value = $_POST['private_photo'];
        
        $sql = "UPDATE photos SET private='$value' WHERE id='$plz_pvt'";
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, get rid of the checkbox with `value="0"`. This doesn't work the way you may expect. If a checkbox is not checked, it's not sent to the server at all. This means that if it IS checked, it's going to send the value `0`, so it will never be set properly.

Next, add a hidden input with the same name and `value="0"`. If this input is placed BEFORE a checkbox, it is sent to the server if the checkbox is not checked. If the checkbox IS checked, it overwrites this hidden input.

```
//ternary - variable holds 'checked' if `$photo_private == 1`, or an empty string if not.
$is_checked = $photo_private == "1" ? 'checked' : '';

//hidden input - Submitted if checkbox is not checked.
echo '<input type="hidden" name="private_photo['.$photo_id.']" value="0">';

//checkbox - overwrites previous hidden input if checked. 
//Utilizes `$is_checked` to check the checkbox by default when appropriate
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="private_photo['.$photo_id.']" value="1" '.$is_checked.'>';
```

This should work because if the checkbox is checked, it will overwrite the value from the hidden input. If it's not checked, the hidden input value will be submitted.